# Laravel Eloquent relations with multiple foreign key with "OR"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I have model `Account` and the account has transactions - model `Transactions`.

In the `Transactions` I have two foreign keys - `from_account_id` and `to_account_id` and both are related to `Account` model.

Now I want to create relations between those two models (e.g. `... WHERE transactions.from_account_id = accounts.id OR transactions.to_account_id = accounts.id`), but Eloquent does not support two foreign keys on relations.

I fount the package topclaudy/compoships, but it does not support OR

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Logically doesn't make sense to have relationship definition on two foreign keys. In your use case the logical relationships would be

```php
class Account extends Model
{
    public function outwardTransactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'from_account_id');
    }

    public function inwardTransactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'to_account_id');
    }
 
    public function allTransactions()
    {
        return $this->outwardTransactions->concat($this->inwardTransactions);
    }

    //Or a local scope on model to get all transactions
    public function scopeWithAllTransactions($query)
    {
        return $query->with(['outwardTransactions', 'inwardTransactions']);
    }
}
```

And relationships on Transaction model can be defined as

```php
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function sourceAccount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'from_account_id', 'id');
    }

    public function destinationAccount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, 'to_account_id', 'id');
    }

    public function accounts()
    {
        return collect([$this->sourceAccount, $this->destinationAccount]);
    }

    //Or a local scope on model to get all accounts
    public function scopeWithAllAccounts($query)
    {
        return $query->with(['sourceAccount', 'destinationAccount']);
    }
}
```

#### Many-to-Many relation

To get near to what you are trying to achieve, an approach would be to use Many-to-Many relation between Account and Transaction model because logically

- a Transaction hasMany Account(s) (two accounts for each transaction)
- an Account (can have) hasMany Transaction(s)

There would be an intermediate linking table `account_transaction` which will have an additional column `type` on it which can contain either **credit** or **debit** as a value.

```php
//account_transaction table
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('account_transaction', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('account_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('transaction_id')->constrained;
        $table->enum('type', ['debit', 'credit']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['account_id', 'transaction_id']);

    });
}

//transactions table
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('amount');
        //any other columns...
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Then relationships can be defined as

```php
class Account extends Model
{
    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Transaction::class)
            ->withPivot('type')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    //... rest of the class code
}

class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function accounts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Account::class)
            ->withPivot('type')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    //... rest of the class code
}
```

Only thing is that while creating an entry for a transaction, you will need to create two corresponding entries in the `account_transaction` table - one for the `from_account` with **debit** type and one for the `to_account` with **credit** type

```php
//Example transaction:
//FromAccountId = 5
//ToAccountId = 20
//Amount = $100

$transaction = Transaction::create(['amount' => 10000]); //100$ x 100 = 10000 cents in database
$transaction->accounts()->attach([
    5 => ['type' => 'debit'],
    20 => ['type' => 'credit'],
]);
```

Then you can perform various queries as required, would also work with querying relationship existence `has`, `whereHas`

```php
$creditTransactions = $account->transactions()->wherePivot('type', 'credit')->get();

$currentDayTransactions = $account->transactions()->whereDate('created_at', now())->get();
```

Comment: Your example is good, only if you are not going to use whereHas :))

Comment: @LevanTetemadze Logically the relationship should be `Many-to-Many` between Account and Transaction models - have updated the answer